# Ubuntu 12.04 cryptsetup failing

Tags: 12.04, boot, encryption

I recently updated my Ubuntu 12.04, and after I restarted the computer just hangs at the following after I type my decrypt password:

```
cryptsetup: sda5_crypt set up successfully
```

I don't know how I can debug as the system does not respond to any commands other than <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>. It is very important for me to save the installation.

Does anyone any idea for a starting point of debugging or recovering?

I am running a Lenovo w520, ubuntu 12.04 64b

*edit: I am able to log into recovery mode, but when I restart I get the same error.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it appears the reason it freezes was not the cryptsetup like it looked like, but change in monitor-setup. I edited my `xorg.conf` file using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and was then able to boot again.

Comment: I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)

Answer (score 0):

Wonderful news! Unplugged my secondary monitor and the display returned. Give it a try gents!

Comment: What about the ladies among your readers? ;-]