# Xubuntu hangs after crypt setup succesfully

Tags: boot, xubuntu, encryption

I have done a clean install of Xubuntu 14.04.1 on a computer with full disk encryption and LVM. It has been working just fine for about three days with no problems.

Now on start up after entering the encryption passphrase, it reads: "cryptsetup: sda5_crypt set up successfully" and has the four blinking dots to show its loading, but it just hangs there and Xubuntu doesn't boot.

After sitting there in an eternal loading loop it does eventually go straight to GRUB. I select "Ubuntu*" to try again and the whole process repeats.

I need help getting Xubuntu to boot normally again after the "sda5_crpyt set up successfully".

It may be worth knowing that I have had a never ending series of problems getting any OS to work on this computer. I have tried Windows 7/8.1, Linux Mint 17.1. Xubuntu 14.04.1 is the only one that hasn't had any installation problems and has been stable after installation.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/311455)?